# Postgresql User Defined Type map to java object Spring JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

what is the easiest way to map POJO to/from PostgreSQL user-defined types?

Answer (score 0):

Wait until Hibernate 6.2 is released. This will happen soon (within 2022) and will come with support for mapping embeddables as structs. Also see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15327